# Typescript ignores decorated mobx properties on class type definition

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript-typings, mobx

This is a simplified example. I have a class definition using decorators like:

```
export default class AnimationController {
  @observable animationTime: number = 0;
  @computed({keepAlive: true}) get interpolatedJoints(){}
  @computed({keepAlive: true}) get currentAnimation(){}
}
```

elsewhere I am importing this class to use as a type definition and getting an error when accessing these expected properties.

```
import AnimationController from './AnimationController';

type Animate = {
  controllers: typeof AnimationController[];
};

//...

        if(
          (this.controllers[0].currentAnimation.name === 'slice' || this.controllers[0].currentAnimation.name === 'punch')
          && this.controllers[0].interpolatedJoints.currentAnimationInfo.lowerKeyframeNumber > 1
          && this.controllers[0].interpolatedJoints.currentAnimationInfo.lowerKeyframeNumber < 4
        ){
```

This throws errors on `.currentAnimation` and `.interpolatedJoints`:

`Property 'currentAnimation' does not exist on type 'typeof AnimationController'. [2339] [2 times]`

`Property 'interpolatedJoints' does not exist on type 'typeof AnimationController'. [2339]`

I am using webpack with the following versions:

```
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
```

my  tsconfig.json looks like the follow9ing

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2019",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `typeof` here:

```
type Animate = {
  controllers: typeof AnimationController[];

  // Should be:
  controllers: AnimationController[];
};
```

`typeof AnimationController` means that you want class constructor, not class instance. But you actually have array of class instances, as far as I understand.

`typeof` could be used in situation like this:

```
class Foo {
  // some code here
}

function createClass(klass: typeof Foo) {
  return new klass();
}


const newInstanceOfFoo = createClass(Foo);
```

Comment: Thanks! that appears to be the issue!